# Kubuntu 20.04 Global Shortcuts / Application Launchers not working

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, launcher, kde5

This is my first installation of Kubuntu 20.04, in an attempt to move from 14.04, on a brand new ASUS laptop. In KDE Menu Editor -> Advanced tab, I am assigning a keyboard shortcut key to a number of menu entries. The same shortcuts are accessible from System Settings -> Shortcuts -> Global Shortcuts -> Application Launchers. None of these shortcuts works. Nothing happens when I press the keys, for a number of key combinations that I have tried, also after a number of system restarts.

An exception is the KRunner Application Launcher (former Global Shortcuts -> Run Command Interface -> Run Command), which was there by default and works fine, whatever shortcut I define.

The are also Global Shortcuts -> Other Shortcuts, which work, more or less. For instance, Global Shortcuts -> Other Shortcuts -> KDE Daemon -> Show System Activity works fine. But, Global Shortcuts -> Other Shortcuts -> Plasma -> Activate Application Launcher Widget only works until restart, when it is automatically reset to the default.

Since some shortcuts are working, I guess this is not a hardware issue. I will only try upgrading one of my existing machines when I am confident that 20.04 works fine for me. This is the only issue so far, but it is critical. I mostly work with shortcuts every day.

Although there are similar questions, I couldn't find anything that would solve my problem. Any idea?

Comment: Open a terminal and type `ls /usr/bin/*session` and let us know what the output is. It will show what desktop you have installed. At least I hope that still works on Kubuntu.

Comment: @darth_epoxy It says dbus-run-session and plasma_session.

Answer (score 0):

KDE Plasma should be the default desktop environment.

To make sure it is, use the following commands from a terminal.
First do a `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get remove kubuntu-desktop`

folloed by
`sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` or if no joy redo this step using **kubuntu-full**
Reboot and try your shortcuts again.

Comment: Thanks. kubuntu-desktop is installed, of course. This is a fresh system installation. There is no kubuntu-full package. There must be a cleaner solution. I am reluctant to try this, now that I have installed and configured everything else.

Comment: sure thing, but at least do the `sudo apt-get update` as the problem may be known (although I didn't find any bugs logged) and the update would then fix it. You can also do 'sudo apt-get upgrade` and before you press **y** check if the desktop is one of the upgrades.

Comment: In the end, I just re-installed everything from scratch. Second time, it took me like a couple of hours. Guess what, no problem this time. I was checking the shortcuts at every step in case anything breaks after a particular installation, but nothing broke. No idea what was wrong.

Comment: The only thing that remains, I think, is the Activate Application Launcher Widget, which is reset to the default at restart. How stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8

Following the suggestions in [this comment](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=421329#c43) on the [related issue](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=421329), I did the following:

1. Renamed *~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc*, then logged out of the Plasma
   session and logged back in. This caused a new
   *~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc* to be created. However, System Settings
   -> Shortcuts -> Global Shortcuts still showed the Application Launcher shortcuts I had set in KMenuEdit, and they still didn't
   work.
2. Removed from System Settings -> Shortcuts -> Global Shortcuts all the Application Launcher shortcuts I had set in
   KMenuEdit, then logged out and logged back in.

New shortcuts set for launchers in KMenuEdit now work as expected.

It may be possible to fix this without recreating *~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc* and just removing the global shortcuts that don't work from System Settings > Shortcuts > Global Shortcuts, then logging out, logging back in and setting the launcher shortcuts anew.